# /bin (and sub) default permissions

Tags: permissions, system-recovery

Long story short, while learning bash scripting etc, I erroneously ran `chmod  -R 770 /bin` (please don't ask why, this is already quite embarrassing as is).

The issue that made me realize the horrible mistake was a denied permission running `/bin/bash` when logging in as user (resulting in a closed SSH connection), and after trying many other solutions found googling, I checked `.bash_history` to find out the comic mistake.

Anyways, is there any way at all to get permissions back to defaults for folder and files? (other than reinstalling the os)

I have a backup of the whole SD (I'm on a headless RasPi running Minibian) not older than 3 days, but I'm not quite sure rolling back the previous version would actually change any permission. Are these details stored in the folder itself, or in some sort of a registry?

Also. Why is it that, despite being the permissions rwx on the user as well as the root, the scripts aren't executed?

Comment: How did you make the backup?

Comment: dd from /sd to .img

Comment: It would be simpler if you can boot to a live USB and mount the Pi and the backup image. Can you do that? Which distro are you using? Please [edit] your question to add clarifications.

Comment: (added above) I'm running Minibian.
And what do you mean by mounting the Pi? In any case, in this very moment the Pi is the only Linux machine I can use, therefore it would be best for me to find a solution working directly on the Pi logged in as root.

Comment: just to be clear, did you mean to guide me through a procedure like the following?
http://superuser.com/questions/132891/how-to-reset-folder-permissions-to-their-default-in-ubuntu/356946#356946

Comment: Yep, something like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32873/discussion-between-kps-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

For a starter, `chmod -R 555 /bin` will get you up and running.

Then `chmod 4755 /bin/ping6 /bin/su /bin/mount /bin/ping /bin/umount` will get your setuid scripts working.

If you didn't mess up `/usr/bin`, your `sudo` should be okay but if not run `chmod 4111 /usr/bin/sudo`.

There is more that should be fixed but this would be the start of a recovery procedure if overwriting that whole directory is not an option.

Comment: simple overwriting can be an option then?

Comment: Should be, if you have a backup.  Just be sure you copy from the backup (a) as root, and (b) with a "preserve permissions and owner" flag set.  (I often use `rsync` rather than `cp` because it is considerably faster for many cases and it is more versatile.)